# Is that good to improve the performance to split the critical section and lock mutex twice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, mutex

I am trying to optimize some multi-threads code. I know the way I should focus on is make the critical section smaller, but I meet some code structure and I am not sure what is the best way to improve the performance.

the first question is like this:

```cpp
mutex.lock();
critical Section A;
func_A(); //func_A() is just a function which will not create confliction.
critical Section B;
mutex.unlock();
```

func_A() is just a function which will not create confliction.
I treat A and B as a whole critical section, If I split the section, let's say, make A and B not in the same critical section like:

```cpp
mutex.lock();
critical Section A;
mutex.unlock();
func_A(); //func_A() is just a function which will not create confliction.
mutex.lock();
critical Section B;
mutex.unlock();
```

will this improve my code performance?

Second question is I have some code like:

```cpp
func1(){
    mutexA.lock();
    critical Section for varibale A;
    mutexB.lock();
    critical Section for varibale B;
    mutexB.unlock();
    critical Section for varibale A;
    mutexA.unlock();
}
func2(){
    if (some condition){
      mutexB.lock();
      critical Section for varibale B;
      mutexB.unlock();
    }
}
```

Here func1 is a time-consuming function and func2 is not.
also, critical Section for variable B is a fast part.

Is that OK for the performance to put one lock inside of another lock? Will it affect the performance too much? Is that OK to just use one mutex for both func1 and func2 rather than 2?

It is really hard to figure out how much these mutexes will cost. I really have no idea for them.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to hold the lock for as little time as possible.  Only profiling though will tell you if you actually gain or not.

Comment: "will this improve my code performance?" - why can't you test it?

Comment: I tested it and the difference is too small. It is hard to see the time costs and it might because of my test cases. And I have no idea of how the performance of mutex works, the only thing I know is to make the critical section as small as possible. But i want to know why and some principle of how should I implement the mutex.

Comment: Why are you calling `mutex.lock()` and `mutex.unlock()` manually, instead of using a scoped lock like `unique_lock` or `lock_guard`? This is an [anti-pattern](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#locking-mutex).

Comment: I am just using the simple code to show how the logic works. I want to know how lower-level works here. it is not my real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, keep it simple, but correct. Then profile. Then, only if required, improve.

Unfortunately I can't provide a more concrete answer here because:

```
mutex.lock();
critical Section A;
database.loadPetabyteOfData() // just a single line
critical Section B;
mutex.unlock();
```

Here it makes a perfect sense. If your "few lines which will not create conflict" are fast - don't bother.

Regarding your last example about using a separate mutex for each variable: usually this doesn't make sense too. If you modify a bunch of variables usually together, protect them by the same mutex. Start from a simpler version.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I edited the question. so if database.loadPetabyteOfData() is not fast i should split the mutex?

Comment: For the second question. I added some thing. the func1 is a time consuming function and tunction 2 is not. That is why i use two mutexes for them.

Comment: if it's not a problem (because it's fast and so splitting doesn't give you any improvement), or not so big problem to pay for a bit more complicated code, I'd suggest the highest priority should be readability/maintainability of your code

Comment: do you have multiple threads that can concurrently execute func1 and func2, and func1 and func2 can be safely executed concurrently? in this case yes, use two separate mutexes

Comment: OK thanks. Yes, and in func2 only if some condition is ture the function will go to the critical part of variable B. I updated the question 2 again.

Answer (score 1):

> will this improve my code performance?

Instead of worrying about performance you should be thinking in terms of correctness. Does it make sense for A and B to happen independently, or should they be a single "atomic" (i.e. indivisible) operation?

If they're separate, independent actions then it might make sense to do:

```
{
  lock_guard<mutex> l(mutex);
  critical section A
}
func_A();
{
  lock_guard<mutex> l(mutex);
  critical section B
}
```

But be aware that this will allow your program to do AAAAAABAABBBBABBBB.

If it's important that it does ABABABABABABABABAB then you need to treat them as a single critical section.

So talking about performance without considering how that affects the actual behaviour is misguided. It's impossible to answer your questions about performance without knowing far more detail about the specifics. But performance is probably not what you should be worrying about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question: If critical sections A and B are time consuming (and independant), then having two separate sections helps two threads to run them concurrently. So, yes, in some cases it may improve the performance.

About your second Q: for light critical sections I always recommend to put them under the same lock. Having less locks helps to avoid deadlocks happening due to programmers mistake as well.

Comment: But func1() is time-consuming and func2 is not. The thing i am considering is that if I use the same mutex for func1 and func2, func2 has to wait for the whole func1 rather than just the variable B.

Comment: @Gavin Xu if func1 is time consuming and func2 is not, it means that the critical section for A is time consuming. So in this case, it is better Not to use the same Mutex for func1 and func2.